# Wrong auth_type when trying to add event on bitrix24 REST-API

Tags: php, rest, bitrix

```
Array
(
    [error] => WRONG_AUTH_TYPE
    [error_description] => Current authorization type is denied for this method
)
```

i´m trying to create an event that triggers when a call starts and it should work for all users, not the ones with admin previleges but even i that have admin privileges get this error so i guess it does not have anything to do with it?
this is the error i get when i run my event handler, i´m new to this so i don´t actually know how the authorization works, i´ve read the documentation but haven´t reached any solutions yet.

**handler.php:**

```php
<?php
require_once (__DIR__.'/crest.php');


class AuthSimple
{
    const AUTH_TYPE = 'demo_simple';

    const AUTH_PARAM_NAME = 'secret_word';
    const AUTH_PARAM_VALUE = 'MySuperSecurePassword123456';

    public static function onRestCheckAuth(array $query, $scope, &$res)
    {
        if(array_key_exists(static::AUTH_PARAM_NAME, $query))
        {
            $res = array('error' => 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS', 'error_description' => 'Invalid request credentials');

            return false;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

$data = file_get_contents('https://gotmink.bitrix24.com.br/rest/4755/uj3p50inofwg6eqm/');

echo '<PRE>';
$result = CRest::call(
    'event.bind',
    [
        'event' => 'OnVoximplantCallInit',
        'handler' => 'https://testebitrix24.herokuapp.com/handler.php',
        'auth_type' => '4755',
        'event_type' => 'online'
    ]
);
print_r($result);

echo '</PRE>';


?>
```